# Create data frame of names of 50 states in R

Tags: r

I'm working on a problem where I'm trying to map each state to a region for some data analysis.  It seems the first thing I need to do is create a dataframe containing the names of all 50 states.  Is there a way to do this without explicitly naming each state and inputting it into a row in the dataframe?

Sample data:

```
region_key <- as.data.frame("") 
colnames(region_key) <- c("state")
region_key$region <- ""
region_key$state <- "AL"
```

I create an empty data frame, create a "state" and "region" column, then populate the state two letter abbreviations in the above fashion.  Is there a way to both populate the data frame with the state abbreviations and classify by region (e.g. Alabama would be "South")?

Expected output:

```
head(region_key)
   state region
1    AL   South
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `data.frame(state.name, state.abb, state.region)`

Comment: @alistaire the only comment I have is to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem based on the comment from @alistair, thank you.

Sample data:

```
region_key <- data.frame(state.abb, state.region)
head(region_key)
     state.abb state.region
1        AL        South
2        AK         West
3        AZ         West
4        AR        South
5        CA         West
6        CO         West
```